# Logging all messages sent to an Akka TestKit TestProbe

Tags: scala, akka, testkit

I'm trying to log all messages *received* by a TestKit TestProbe, which is proving to be somewhat difficult. I'm aware of the [Actor Logging](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html#actor-logging-scala) section in the docs where it says one should use the `debug.receive` option in combination with a `LogginReceive` block. This however doesn't work when I'm not in control of the actor's implementation.

The only idea I had was subclassing `akka.testkit.TestActor` to use a `LoggingReceive` and then subclass `TestKit` to make it create instances of my `TestActor` subclass instead, but that didn't work because most functionality there is private to the `akka` namespace (and for good reason, I suppose).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, got your question a little wrong at first, so here is my approach.

Create a wrapper actor, that logs the messages:

```
class LoggingActor(fac: => Actor) extends Actor {

  val underlying = context.system.actorOf(Props(fac))

  def receive = {
    LoggingReceive {
      case x ⇒ underlying.tell(x, sender)
    }
  }
}
```

and then just create your `TestActorRef` with your actor wrapped in the `LoggingActor`:

```
  val echo = TestActorRef(new LoggingActor(new FooActor))

  echo ! "hello world"
```

Answer (score 15):

There is a (probably surprisingly) simple answer:

```
probe.setAutoPilot(new TestActor.AutoPilot {
  def run(sender: ActorRef, msg: Any) = {
    log.debug("whatever")
    this
  }
})
```

Comment: maybe simpler, but somehow cryptic. What's an AutoPilot? The doc is silent on that.

Comment: AutoPilot is in docs now, fyi. Not the simplest concept but the above code is pretty straightforward and does the trick (I just log sender & msg values instead of "whatever" literal, obviously).

Answer (score 5):

Using Ronald's answer I wrote this to have a simpler way to define my probes:

```
object LoggingTestProbe {
  def apply()(implicit system: ActorSystem) : TestProbe = {
    val probe = TestProbe()
    probe.setAutoPilot(new TestActor.AutoPilot {
      def run(sender: ActorRef, msg: Any) = {
        val other = sender.path
        val me = probe.ref.path
        system.log.debug(s"$me received $msg from $other")
        this
      }
    })
    probe
  }
}
```

Having this I define my probes using `LoggingTestProbe()` instead of `TestProbe()`.

I'm new to Scala so this might not be optimal but works great for me.